# Can't find what the unexpected token is on (19:9) React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native

I have been following a tutorial with React Native and emulating the result using Xcode's iPhone emulator, however I'm stuck on this error message and cannot see what's wrong. I have another file which is importing this component to be within the NavigatorIOS component.

```js
var React = require('react-native');

var {
 View,
 StyleSheet,
 Text
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create ({
 mainContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#eee'
 }
});

class Main extends React.Component {
 render: function() {
        return (
            <Text>
             Hello
            </Text>
        )
    }
};

module.exports = Main;
```

Comment: Are you transpiling your code with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)? The syntax you're using is in ES6 / ES2015.

Comment: No I'm just using Xcode and writing Javascript, I usually use CoffeeScript, but as I'm just getting started on React Native I thought i'd learn the JS way first. I don't actually know about Babel, but have heard it come up a lot recently.

Answer (score 11):

Inside class bodies, methods are declared with

```
render() { ... }
```

**not**

```
render: function() { ... }
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for more information.

Comment: Tnx dude,solved. But in official documents: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html defines: `... render: function() { ...`

Comment: @chalist: If you look closely, the tutorial uses `React.createClass({...})` to create components, not ES6 classes (`class Component extends React.Component`). Object literals and classes are two different things, hence their syntax is different. You can find more information about classes in React in http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html .